# QML semicircle slider

Tags: slider, qml, qt5

I read [this tutorial](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/custom_control_tutorial.html) how to create a circle slider in QML.
I think, that I can edit this code for semicircle instead of circle. But problem that this example for Blackberry OS and need inheriting from bb::cascades::CustomControl class and in source code exists includes from bb::cascades namespace.

Is exist native Qt5 way for creating semicircle slider?

Comment: You have at least 2 ways to create your own control:  instance of a class inherites from `QQuickItem` (OpenGL painting) or from  `QQuickPaintedItem` (`QPainter`). There are a lots of examples over the Internet how to do that. You can take BB example as a base.

Comment: @folibis thank you for answer, but my problem that in source code from tutoiral exist next headers from bb::cascades.

Comment: Don't take the source, take the idea. You can create all control you want using only `QQuickItem`. Look  [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html) how to create own graphical item